# How to update props after getting fetch data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, react-props

i am trying to get data from fetch , and ''refresh'' the page , with new props that their value is the data from fetch

submit = () => {

```
let user = {
  email: this.props.email,
  newuser: this.state.new_username
};

fetch("http://192.168.2.45/backend/public/api/update", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(user),
  headers: new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  })
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(responseJson=>Actions.refresh({username:responseJson}) )
  .catch(error => console.error("error:", error));
```

};

render() {
    return (

```
    <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text style={styles.name}>{this.props.username}</Text>

    </View>
```

i am trying in someway take the responseJson and update with its value my props.username , but it does not seem to update

Comment: Are you using a state management framework like redux?

Comment: No because i had to update some things  and that caused me many issues....so i just use this  ==> class Parent { ..... render() {return <Child.Component {...this.state} 
   }

Comment: do you want help with setting that up? I think that would also fix this issue for you :)

Comment: one guy above solved for me , but still thanks mate :)

Comment: hahah oh you solved it ! dont worry man you already fixed my problem :)

Comment: Nah that wasn't me ;) I would highly recommend you avoid making requests from your component and using local state for those request responses. If you unmount that component (user navigates away for instance), then you are setting state on an unmounted component. Which can break your application :/

Comment: ok i see.. ok so i will try it again with redux ! thanks !

Comment: Yep! Feel free to ping/mention me if you have issues with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props are read-only, so you can't directly update them from within the component that receives them. State is the mechanism for changes like this. It sounds like you're getting an initial state from the parent, so there are a few different things you could do deal with that.

One thing would be to have your fetch happen in the parent component, update the parent's state, and pass the state value down to this component as props. That way there's no conflict between props and state.

Another possibility would be just to supply state if it's truthy and otherwise fall back to props.

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = {
    username: ""
  }
}
render() {
  return (
    <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text style={styles.name}>{this.state.username || this.props.username}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

This is one way that will *basically* work, but is not recommended by React.

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = {
    username: props.username
  }
}
```

(In all these cases, you would update the state when you fetch the data, as Roopak PutheVeettil says in their comment.)

There are more complex things you can do using `componentDidUpdate()` and `getDerivedStateFromProps()` if you truly have to synthesize an updating state and props that can change over time, but you shouldn't need that here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `State` Instead of `Props`

```
 fetch("http://192.168.2.45/backend/public/api/update", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
      headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(responseJson=>this.setState({username:responseJson}) )
      .catch(error => console.error("error:", error));

    <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Text style={styles.name}>{this.state.username}</Text>

        </View>
```

Comment: well the thing is i have to use props , because before the submit function executes , i take the ''this.props.username'' from parent component

Comment: i wouldn't recommend making requests from the component like this. Setting local state from the request deferred is a bad pattern/practice.

Comment: i am guessing you are referring to the guy above ?because i have not used setState in fetch request

Comment: @Vagtse yes, this comment was directed to the owner of this answer :)